# t-test shows significant differences when graph doesn't

Tags: standard-deviation, excel

I've made t-test in excel with my samples and the graph showing mean values with standard deviation. t-test shows significant difference, when standard deviation lines cross on the graph. Could you please explain what's can be wrong with it?

[image]

Comment: Could you please show your graph? Would you be able to provide more info?

Comment: I've added I graph to my question

Comment: Why do you think an overlap of those "error bars" on your dynamite plot indicate much that's relevant to the question of whether the means differ? When you look at the plot, you're effectively comparing at $|\bar{x}_1-\bar{x}_2|$  to $s_1+s_2$ but instead you should be comparing $|\bar{x}_1-\bar{x}_2|$ to its standard error, which will tend to be much smaller than $s_1+s_2$. The plot is very uninformative about significance.

Answer (score 3):

The t-test considers standard error, which is related to but not synonymous with standard deviation. A quick word on the difference is that the standard error divides the standard deviation by the sample size. (A more detailed explanation would get into how you estimate the standard deviation.)

Consequently, it is find that the standard deviations overlap like they do yet the test rejects. As the sample size gets large, the standard errors shrink arbitrarily small, no matter how large the standard deviation is, and the t-test will reject even small differences in the means.

Excel seems to be doing statistics correctly.